# How it works: Magic Methods in PHP and understanding them by logic not by definitions

Tags: php, opencart

Good day to you all!
I have the following example (from Opencart):

home.php:

```
<?php
class ControllerCommonHome extends Controller {
    public function index() {
        $this->document->setTitle($this->config->get('config_meta_title'));
        $this->document->setDescription($this->config->get('config_meta_description'));
        $this->document->setKeywords($this->config->get('config_meta_keyword'));

        if (isset($this->request->get['route'])) {
            $this->document->addLink(HTTP_SERVER, 'canonical');
        }

        $data['column_left'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_left');
        $data['column_right'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_right');
        $data['content_top'] = $this->load->controller('common/content_top');
        $data['content_bottom'] = $this->load->controller('common/content_bottom');
        $data['footer'] = $this->load->controller('common/footer');
        $data['header'] = $this->load->controller('common/header');

        if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/common/home.tpl')) {
            $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view($this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/common/home.tpl', $data));
        } else {
            $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('default/template/common/home.tpl', $data));
        }
    }
}
```

controller.php:

```
<?php
abstract class Controller {
    protected $registry;

    public function __construct($registry) {
        $this->registry = $registry;
    }

    public function __get($key) {
        return $this->registry->get($key);
    }

    public function __set($key, $value) {
        $this->registry->set($key, $value);
    }
}
```

I cannot make a logical process to understand how this works:

1. Where is "document" and setTitle(...) ?
   $this->document->setTitle($this->config->get('config_meta_title'));
2. Where is "config" and get(...) ?
   $this->document->setDescription($this->config->get('config_meta_description'));

How is this working ? I cannot see / think this process in mind...
I can read about it, but having blanks when trying to redo it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__set` and `__get` are called when loading or setting a property:

```
$this->property = 'value'; // calls __set
echo $this->property; // calls __get.
```

Your `get()` requests are handled by `__call`

```
$this->get('foo'); // calls __call
Object::get('foo'); // calls __callStatic
```

See documentation about magic methods: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call

Also in your example of the controller any __get or __set is redirected to the registry class methods `get` and `set`.

So if in your example $this is a class extending the abstract class Controller:

```
$this->title = 'foo'; // redirected to registry set
echo $this->title; // redirected to registry get
```

From your posted code it's very hard to identify what document is. Document however is loaded through the registry get. So:

```
// request
$this->document->setTitle('foo');
// calls magic method __get
// calls $this->registry->get('document');
// returns the value in registry for document, which might be an object; let's hope so
// now run the method setTitle('foo') on the object returned from the registry
```

Answer (score 0):

The PHP __get and __set magic methods essentially get called when you reference a property/attribute of an object that doesn't exist. You can then return whatever you want instead using the property/attribute name as the key (which is passed as a parameter to those functions).  In the above case it is returning an object from the registry based on the key (being the property/attribute name).

To find the source "document" object you will need to understand how it was registered in the registry in the first place.  This most likely occurred during the application bootstrapping process.  I'm not familiar with OpenCart but there will be somewhere that items are registered in the registry.  Once you find that you will be able to see what sort of object is being instantiated and stored into that registry.